# Merge DataGridView Image cell with text cell

Tags: c#, vb.net, image, winforms, datagridview

I'm looking for cell painting code to merge a datagridview image cell with a text cell, like the image to be on top and text at the bottom. 
I was asked to find a way of showing people pictures with job title and department. I was able to merge job title and department into one cell but not image with text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In its simplest form you could code the `CellPainting` event like this:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellPainting(object sender,
                                        DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.RowIndex < 0) return;                  // no image in the header
    if (e.ColumnIndex == yourImageColumn )
    {
        e.PaintBackground(e.ClipBounds, false);  // no highlighting
        e.PaintContent(e.ClipBounds);

        // calculate the location of your text..:
        int y = e.CellBounds.Bottom - 35;         // your  font height
        e.Graphics.DrawString(yourText, yourFont, yourColor, e.CellBounds.Left, y);
        // maybe draw more text with other fonts etc..
        ..
        e.Handled = true;                        // done with the image column 
    }
}
```

To set the size and alignment of the image cell you can use code like this, after the Image has been set:

```
// add space for two lines:
dataGridView1.Rows[0].Height = ((Image)dataGridView1[0, 0].Value).Height + 35;
// if the previous line throws an error..
// .. because you didn't put a 'real image' into the cell try this:
// dataGridView1.Rows[0].Height = 
     ((Image)dataGridView1[0, 0]. FormattedValue).Height + 35;

// align the image top left:
dataGridView2[0, 0].Style.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.TopLeft;
```

Obviously you will have to adapt the numbers according to the Fonts and Font sizes you want to use..

Here is the result with two lines of text below the image:

[image]

An alternative worth considering may be to combine the `Image` with text on the fly..

Comment: Thanks for this, it's good idea but I don't want the text to be writen on picture, but more on a row just below the picture.

Comment: The code above will do just that, if your Row.Height is larger than the Image.Height. See the update with an example..!

Comment: Thanks again. now I got  Unable to cast object of type 'System.Byte[]' to type 'System.Drawing.Image'.

Comment: Well my code was just an example. you will need to adapt it to your situation, e.g. the column idex also make the rowindex dynamic etc.. . In this case you need to get access to the dimensions of the images; you may succeed casting them to Bitmap instead but the best course of action imo is to store image information right where you import and store these  images. I assume they come from a database? Do they all have the same size?

Comment: Please try to replace `Value` with  `FormattedValue`in the line that give you the error. You still probably should use the size data if you know them anyway but its could be an interesting test!